# Error on upgrading TYPO3 7.6 to 8.7 (Upgrade Wizard Error)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I am experiencing a problem when updating an TYPO3 project from version 7.6.X to 8.7.X.

When I use the Upgrade Wizard, an error occurs. 
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE0YX.png)

This link is used for the Upgrade Wizard:
`install.php?&install[action]=upgradeWizard&install[controller]=tool&install[context]=standalone)`

[This is my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oXX8.png)

[Link to Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcQTN.png)

All the best
anonykatz

Here what the Database Analyzer prints out.

```
Database analysis failed
[SQL Error] line 0, col 142: Error: Expected NOT, NULL, DEFAULT, AUTO_INCREMENT, UNIQUE, PRIMARY, COMMENT, COLUMN_FORMAT, STORAGE or REFERENCES, got 'on' in statement:
CREATE TABLE link_cache ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, params blob, url char(255), tstamp TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, crdatetime datetime default NULL, sticky tinyint(1) unsigned default 0, PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY url (url(255)), KEY params (params(255)) );
```

Comment: Hi anonykatz. Welcome to the stack overflow community. Please update (edit) your question and let us know what exactly the error message is. Maybe create a screenshot too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a screenshot.

Comment: You need review the error log of your web server in order to look up what exactly the issue is. You will likely discover a PHP error (that is not shown in the web output for security reasons).

Comment: One of a lot of possible problems could be misconfigured links in tt_content.bodytext. There are solutions for this issue. Nevertheless at the moment you don't have a useful errormessage. Try to: Look into the PHP errorlog and post the problem, try to turn on errormessages in Install Tool for your TYPO3-Instance or try to login with the same browser at the same time into backend to get a useful error message. Please keep us up-to-date.

Comment: I added the Errors from Typo3 to the main post.

Comment: If you run into errors regarding missing tables or columns, try to run the Database Analyzer once. Not the full thing, only see if new fields/tables are available to be added, and execute them (the ones that are preselected).

Comment: The Database Analyzer says
Database analysis failed
[SQL Error] line 0, col 142: Error: Expected NOT, NULL, DEFAULT, AUTO_INCREMENT, UNIQUE, PRIMARY, COMMENT, COLUMN_FORMAT, STORAGE or REFERENCES, got 'on' in statement:
CREATE TABLE link_cache ( id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, params blob, url char(255), tstamp TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, crdatetime datetime default NULL, sticky tinyint(1) unsigned default 0, PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY url (url(255)), KEY params (params(255)) );`

Comment: check if in your ext_tables.sql there is the word  'on'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an update you need to do some thing first.

---

**Check extension compatibility**

Make a list of the installed extension and search the TER or their origin if there is an available version for the targeted TYPO3 version.

**Uninstall the third party extensions**

Once you have done that and all the extensions are compatible with the targeted TYPO3 version you need to uninstall all the third party extensions in order to avoid conflicts such as database missing fields.

**Backup your files**

Take your fileadmin or any file storage and create a .zip file. The same with the ext folder under the **typo3conf/ext**. After you 've done that, create an SQL dump, meaning create a database backup/copy.

At this point you have a backup in case something goes wrong with the update. Plus it is way quicker uploading your files as one file (zip) instead uploading them one by one.

**Update TYPO3**

Depending on the mode you 're in, update your TYPO3.

If it is on **composer mode**, then include the TYPO3 Version you want to install on your **composer.json** file. Do the same with the extensions. Rememeber that you deactivated all the third party extensions so once you install the new version, the tables will be re-read and all the changes will be taken to conisderation.

If it is "**manual mode**" then download the TYPO3 version you want to install via zip/tar/gz and extract it on your project path. For the extensions, you need to first wait to complete the steps on the install tool to make sure you have access on the Backend.

**Analyze Database**

Once you 've done everything, go to your Install Tool and perform the **Database Analyse**.
Follow the steps that the analyser says you should folllow.

**Upgrade Wizard**

Go to the **upgrade wizard** and follow the steps one by one. Sometimes some steps are not necessary unless you absolutely need them (eg compatibility7).

**Install the extension**

After you completed the TYPO3 core update, it is time to install the extensions. I would recommend to activate the extension one by one and test their functionality before installing the next extension. So if you get an error, you know which extension causes it.

If you are on **composer mode** then you just need to activate them.

If you are on "**manual mode**" then you need to go to the extension module and search for the new version of each extension, download and install it.

---

If i forgot something feel free to edit the psot, or correct me

Best regards